# Формирование данных для ajax-запроса

Tags: jquery, ajax

В общем есть такой кодик, сдается мне формирую массив для отправки на сервер не очень гуманно, как бы сделать это более профессионально? Речь о семи строках после комментария в коде `//формирую массив данных`

```js
$(function() {

  //сохранить
  $('#saveBtn').on('click', _saveDepts);

  //сохранение отделений
  function _saveDepts() {

    var _dataSend = {};
    _dataSend.action = 2;

    //тестовые данные
    _dataSend.test = [{
      "id": "3179",
      "nid": "37",
      "oid": "1",
      "town": "Ростов-на-Дону",
      "service": "Красные слоны",
      "address": "Ростов-на-Дону, ул. Вокзальная, 7",
      "coord": "47.222531, 39.718705",
      "tid": "628",
      "sid": "32"
    }, {
      "id": "3180",
      "nid": "37",
      "oid": "2",
      "town": "Ростов-на-Дону",
      "service": "Красные слоны",
      "address": "Ростов-на-Дону, ул. Тракторная, 37",
      "coord": "47.264931, 39.68827",
      "tid": "628",
      "sid": "32"
    }]


    //формирую массив данных
    _dataSend.data = [];
    $('.row').each(function(index, element) {
      _dataSend.data[index] = {};
      $(this).find('input').each(function(i, el) {
        _dataSend.data[index][$(el).attr('name').slice(0, -2)] = $(el).val();
      });
    });
    //конец

    console.log(_dataSend);
    $('#output').html(JSON.stringify(_dataSend));
    
    $.ajax({
        url: 'query.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: _dataSend
      })
      .done(function() {
        console.log("success");
      })
      .fail(function() {
        console.log("error");
      });
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-inline" id="rows">
  <div class="row">
    <input type="hidden" value="3179" name="id[]">
    <input type="text" value="37" name="nid[]">
    <input type="text" value="1" name="oid[]">
    <input type="text" value="Ростов-на-Дону" name="town[]">
    <input type="text" value="Красные слоны" name="service[]">
    <input type="text" value="Ростов-на-Дону, ул. Вокзальная, 7" name="address[]">
    <a class="getCoord" href="#">&gt;&gt;</a>
    <input type="text" value="47.222531, 39.718705" name="coord[]">
    <a class="deleteRow" href="#">x</a>
    <input type="hidden" value="628" name="tid[]">
    <input type="hidden" value="32" name="sid[]">
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <input type="hidden" value="3178" name="id[]">
    <input type="text" value="39" name="nid[]">
    <input type="text" value="1" name="oid[]">
    <input type="text" value="Ростов-на-Дону" name="town[]">
    <input type="text" value="Зеленые слоны" name="service[]">
    <input type="text" value="Ростов-на-Дону, ул. Ленина, 27" name="address[]">
    <a class="getCoord" href="#">&gt;&gt;</a>
    <input type="text" value="47.283138, 39.620546" name="coord[]">
    <a class="deleteRow" href="#">x</a>
    <input type="hidden" value="628" name="tid[]">
    <input type="hidden" value="33" name="sid[]">
  </div>
</div>

<input type="button" id="saveBtn" value="Сохранить" class="btn btn-success"><div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: что значит _не очень гуманно_?

Comment: @grundy может row .map() return input .map() return val() было бы элегантнее? Не смог.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае `each` используется, в качестве `map`, поэтому его можно на него и заменить.

```
_dataSend.data = $('.row').map(function(index, element) {...})
```

Однако, [`map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) возвращает объект jQuery, следовательно, для получения обычного массива, нужно добавить вызов [toArray](http://api.jquery.com/toArray/)

Из функции `map`, нужно вернуть объект, но так как функция [find](http://api.jquery.com/find/) возвращает ArrayLike объект jQuery, можно воспользоваться функцией [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

```
[].reduce.call(
        $(this).find('input'), function(acc, el) {
          acc[$(el).attr('name').slice(0, -2)] = $(el).val();
          return acc;
        },{})
```

Кроме того, стоит подумать о хранении имени в отдельном дата атрибуте. это позволит избавится от `slice`

Пример:

```js
$(function() {

  //сохранить
  $('#saveBtn').on('click', _saveDepts);

  //сохранение отделений
  function _saveDepts() {

    var _dataSend = {};
    _dataSend.action = 2;

    //тестовые данные
    _dataSend.test = [{
      "id": "3179",
      "nid": "37",
      "oid": "1",
      "town": "Ростов-на-Дону",
      "service": "Красные слоны",
      "address": "Ростов-на-Дону, ул. Вокзальная, 7",
      "coord": "47.222531, 39.718705",
      "tid": "628",
      "sid": "32"
    }, {
      "id": "3180",
      "nid": "37",
      "oid": "2",
      "town": "Ростов-на-Дону",
      "service": "Красные слоны",
      "address": "Ростов-на-Дону, ул. Тракторная, 37",
      "coord": "47.264931, 39.68827",
      "tid": "628",
      "sid": "32"
    }]


    //формирую массив данных
    _dataSend.data = $('.row').map(function(index, element) {
      return [].reduce.call(
        $(this).find('input'), function(acc, el) {
          acc[$(el).attr('name').slice(0, -2)] = $(el).val();
          return acc;
        },{});
    }).toArray();
    //конец

    console.log(_dataSend);
    $('#output').html(JSON.stringify(_dataSend));

    $.ajax({
        url: 'query.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: _dataSend
      })
      .done(function() {
        console.log("success");
      })
      .fail(function() {
        console.log("error");
      });
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-inline" id="rows">
  <div class="row">
    <input type="hidden" value="3179" name="id[]">
    <input type="text" value="37" name="nid[]">
    <input type="text" value="1" name="oid[]">
    <input type="text" value="Ростов-на-Дону" name="town[]">
    <input type="text" value="Красные слоны" name="service[]">
    <input type="text" value="Ростов-на-Дону, ул. Вокзальная, 7" name="address[]">
    <a class="getCoord" href="#">&gt;&gt;</a>
    <input type="text" value="47.222531, 39.718705" name="coord[]">
    <a class="deleteRow" href="#">x</a>
    <input type="hidden" value="628" name="tid[]">
    <input type="hidden" value="32" name="sid[]">
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <input type="hidden" value="3178" name="id[]">
    <input type="text" value="39" name="nid[]">
    <input type="text" value="1" name="oid[]">
    <input type="text" value="Ростов-на-Дону" name="town[]">
    <input type="text" value="Зеленые слоны" name="service[]">
    <input type="text" value="Ростов-на-Дону, ул. Ленина, 27" name="address[]">
    <a class="getCoord" href="#">&gt;&gt;</a>
    <input type="text" value="47.283138, 39.620546" name="coord[]">
    <a class="deleteRow" href="#">x</a>
    <input type="hidden" value="628" name="tid[]">
    <input type="hidden" value="33" name="sid[]">
  </div>
</div>

<input type="button" id="saveBtn" value="Сохранить" class="btn btn-success">
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, спасибо, не обратил внимания :)

Comment: Изначально форма сабмитилась без js, поэтому имена nid[]  для формирования массива $_REQUEST[ ]. Подумал возможно пригодится еще.

Comment: @Jean-Claude, я имел ввиду добавить атрибут `data-name` - и в скрипте его использовать. а не обычный `name` - в котором оставить стандартную запись, на случай отключенного js

Comment: а что за аргументы в коллбеке reduce - `acc, el` - должны же быть вроде [previousValue, currentValue](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)? `call` подменяет их на другие аргументы, как понять на какие?

Comment: @Jean-Claude, в callback'е для reduce, количество параметров как было так и осталось, и по приведенной ссылке показано. что их 4, а не 2. Единственное отличие в вызовах функций func()  и finc.call() - то что первый параметр для call - это контекст. т.е. следующие вызовы эквивалентны: `a.func()` ~ `a.func.call(a)`. Подробнее в справке по [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

Comment: тогда откуда взялись `function(acc, el)` ?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38187/discussion-between-grundy-and-jean-claude).